# What is ceramic tin made of?

Tags: material-identification

does anyone know what ceramic tins are made of? I bought [a ceramic tin of sweets](https://lafortaleza.net/surtidos-navidenos-estepa/dulces-de-espana/) and the tin itself just doesn't feel like the traditional ceramics that I know of. I found [a list of different types of ceramics](https://farandaway.co/blogs/the-artisan/types-of-ceramics), but I am just not sure what type of ceramics the ceramic tin I bought belong to. If I have posted the question in the wrong forum, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. The picture looks like a metal tin and the listing describes it as a metal case. Can you clarify where the ceramic question comes from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, the tin you have purchased is **not ceramic at all**. The listing specifies the material used:

> METALLIC BOX 350G

"Ceramic" in the title and description refers not to the material from which the box is made, but to the *decoration* on the box:

> Original design, where the characteristic ocher and indigo tones stand out, which **recalls the most traditional Sevillian ceramic art**. **Meticulous illustrations**, made with the collaboration of master ceramicists, make this container a treasure both inside and out. Mantecados, Polvorones, Roscos de vino*…

(Translated by Google Translate)

The box itself is a standard metal container; it doesn't "feel like traditional ceramics" because it isn't ceramic.

Comment: There is a 99.9 % chance the "tin" is steel . With zinc or  tin coating. A magnet will identify it.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance and help! Happy holidays ~